# UITextField Chinese character moves down when editing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c

The environment that I'm using is Xcode8 and iOS10 .

**What did i do:**
In IB , drag an `UITextField` into my main view ,add some constraints to place the textfield in the right place , select the textfield's border style to none, at last, type some text to make the UITextField resize in storyboard ,like below:
[image: TextField in storyboard]

In order to see what's going on , i also make the textfield to draw its boundary by adding this in `viewDidLoad`:
`self.textField.layer.borderWidth = 1;`

Build and run , it looks good on device:

[image]

**The Problem**

However,if i try to edit the textfield (when the textfield becomes first responder) , the text moves down :

[image]

This issue occurs only when setting the Textfield's border style to none and the text contains Chinese characters , does anyone has a clue of what's happening here ?

Comment: Most lkely the textfield is not high enough for the text.

Comment: @gnasher729 , that shouldn't be the case, since i adjust the font size in the storyboard and let the textfield to resize itself , and when it's not editing or the border style is not none , everything works fine.

Comment: Same issue here. Now we just use .Line border style and set the border color to our background color as a workaround. But it is not perfect since the same thing will happen if the text content exceeds the text field width. :(

Comment: @onevcat ,this might be just another bug of the storyboard , try to set the borderStyle in code instead ,i fix this by setting the borderStyle to UITextBorderStyleLine in IB ,and change it to UITextBorderStyleNone in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue to me. I use `UIAlertView` contain `UITextField`, I fix it by setting:

```
 textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

That's ok.

Another method is : subclass `UITextField`, rewrite:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    return CGRectInset(bounds, 2, 1);

}


- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 2, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I fix this issue by setting the borderStyle to anything but `UITextBorderStyleNone` in the interface builder , and then in my vc's `viewDidLoad` , change it to `UITextBorderStyleNone` , i suppose that this is just another one of many bugs that the interface builder has ? :)

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is great. I tried it out and it's possible to just do this in the code (no need to change anything in Interface Builder:
`self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;`

Also, if you're using a custom UIView subclass (an UITableViewCell or such), place the code in `-awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Chinese character when using `UITextField`. The text display in the right rect if text is short and no scroll in `UITextField`. When `UITextField` cannot display the text in the visible rect and becomes scrollable, the text will draw below the central line if click delete button on the keyboard.

After `NSLOG` subviews of `UITextField` in the `layoutSubviews` func, it shows the subview named `UITextEditor` has the wrong `contentOffset`.

So I override the `layoutSuviews` func, reset the `contentOffset.y` of `UITextEditor` after call `[super layoutSubview]`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIScrollView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            CGPoint offset = view.contentOffset;
            if (offset.y != 0) {
                offset.y = 0;
                view.contentOffset = offset;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change UITextField height to right height

1、get size of font

```
  CGSize size = [@"你好" sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
```

2、set textFiled height and font size

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 150, size.height);

 UITextField  textFiled = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

 [textFiled setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
```

Hope can help you！

Answer (score 0):

We use storyboard, however, we face the same issue.
After some investigating, we decide to use IBInspectable to do the hack.
Every UITextField in the storyboard will raise the IBInspectable flag and the problem will be solved.
This is swift version:

```
extension UITextField {

  @IBInspectable var hideBorder: Bool {
    get {
      return borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.none
    }
    set {
      if newValue {
        borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
        borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
      }
    }
  }

}
```